# MySQL to count total number of specimens

Tags: mysql

I have to get total number of specimens in the database.

**Table1**:
[image]

There are 5 specimens as shown in the figure: user 1 has 2, user 2 has 2 and user 3 has 1 number of specimens (users are asked to type a word a number of times and each word is called here a specimen,e.g., cat, bird etc).

I tried following query:

```
Select count(distinct userId) from  Table1 group by userId
```

It shows user ID wise total specimens. But what I need is total number of specimens inclusive of all users,i.e, 5.

Comment: Try `count(distinct userId, specimens)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **select distinct** with multiple columns:

[How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns)

Then you can apply count(*) to the result:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct userId, specimen from Table1);
```

Note that it works not with MySQL only but with other dialects as well (including SQLite).